# Spark/Scala - Failed to execute user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code that works.

```scala
val locList = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/locations.txt")).getLines().toList

def locCheck(col: String): Boolean = locList.contains(col)
def locUDF = udf[Boolean, String](locCheck)
```

But when I add a `toUpperCase` to make it

```scala
val locList = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/locations.txt")).getLines().toList

def locCheck(col: String): Boolean = locList.contains(col.toUpperCase)
def locUDF = udf[Boolean, String](locCheck)
```

I run into a `Failed to execute user defined function` caused by `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I using the udf as `df.filter(locUDF('location)).count()`

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it ?

Comment: can you share the full code where you use udf function?

Comment: @koiralo I've added the code for calling the udf

Comment: Make sure that you don't have null values in `location` column if `location` is null then col is null and throws NPE in `col.toUpperCase`

Comment: @koiralo, I do have null values. How do I handle them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the function or `udf`. The problem is with the data that comes into the `udf`.

Here in your case if the column `location` have a `null` values, When you pass those values to `udf` the value of `col` is `null`.

Then You get a `NullPointerException` when you call `col.toUpperCase` in case col is null.

You can simply check the null values in function

```
def locCheck(col: String): Boolean = if (col == null) false else locList.contains(col.toUpperCase)
```

Or you can use Options to handle this as

```
def locCheck(col: String): Boolean =locList.contains(Option(col).map(_.toUpperCase))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, all the columns seem to have the same issue

Comment: Fixed it, the source data had some non-ascii characters which was affecting the inputStream. Once that was fixed, you solution for handling null worked great. Thank you !